# CRM OData OrganizationData.svc does not work by IP

Tags: javascript, iis, odata, crm

I have been working on CRM autoupdate filed and i got it working by

```
var lookUpObjectValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_kdid").getValue();    
if ((lookUpObjectValue != null))    
{ 
  var lookupid = lookUpObjectValue[0].id;    
  var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();    
  var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";    
  var odataSetName = "new_kdSet?";    
  var odataSelect = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName  +     
  "$select=new_City" +    
  "&$filter=new_kdId eq (guid'" + lookupid + "')" +     
          "&$top=1";    
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",    
        url: odataSelect,    
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },    
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest){
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").setValue(data.d.results[0].new_City);      

    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect); }      
});
```

}

And it works fine until I connect to CRM by IP. 
Like http://193.92.1.4/CRMTest/main.aspx# instead of 
crm-server01/CRMTest/main.aspx

then i get the error  OData Select Failed:/*Some url that start with crm-server01/ ... */ and when i run it it get the right data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to cross site scripting. You will find this happens to a lot of different JavaScript doing requests on CRM.

I would recommend only connecting to CRM using your server name.